# Application that shows rar-archives as normal files

Tags: windows, file-compression

Does anyone know of a software that allows mapping whole folders/drives (not just one archive) and show rar/zip/..-archive content as plain files?

To be used with for example Plex as they removed archive-support a couple years ago.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and explain more about what you mean by "normal" and "plain" files? Are they the actual files contained in an archive, or a text document with a list of these files for example?

Comment: yeah, the contained files in the archive.. can be pretty much any type of file I guess.. dunno how it would handle nested archives tho.

Comment: Are you only interested in a graphical interface or would a command line solution be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WinMount](http://www.winmount.com/) to mount multiple archives as a virtual drive. WinMount has a free version, 
and a paid version. The free version imposes a 20mb archive size limit, the paid version is $49, and has a free trial.
 Rar is a supported archive format. The archives will each be mounted as their own folder in the virtual drive, except
 the first archive which will function as the drive root.

## Steps:

1. (Purchase), download, and install WinMount.

[image: mount to]

[image: browsing]

2. Run WinMount, choose `Mount To`, and browse for the files you wish to mount. If your files are in the same directory
   you can choose them all at once, if they aren't you'll have to mount one, and then need to right click on the virtual drive listing, and choose
   `insert archive` to add more archives; you can add and remove individual archives at your leisure.

[image: prompt]

3. If you are running WinMount as a trial you will get a popup asking if you want to buy WinMount or continute as
   a trial, click `Continue The Trial` to proceed with the mount.

[image: letter]

4. Choose an unused letter to mount under.

[image: open]

5. Click `Open Drive` at the bottom to browse the virtual drive. If auto open is enabled you won't have to.