# Windows Explorer that open popular zip files like normal files and folders

Tags: windows, file-compression

Noted that the Windows Explorer in Windows 8, 8.1, 10 are able to open zip files and treat them like normal files and folders.

So, was wondering if there is a better than Windows Explorer that fulfill most of the requirements below:

- gratis
- portable (do not need to install. can just put into thumb-drive and use from there)
- at least support Windows 7 operating system and onward.
- not just open zip file. can also open rar files, 7z files, and many popular compression file format.
- treat all compressed file as normal files and folders
- allow editing of files inside the compressed file and save instantaneous. (e.g. open a text file and edit and click save, just like editing a normal file)
- allow open of PDF files inside the compressed file directly without extracting. (Important)
- allow open of multimedia files inside the compressed file (such as movie or music or picture that is in the compressed file) without the need to extract. (Important)
- compression rate must be at least 1% or more
- GUI interface is more preferable.

This question is different from that question - [Archive file format / viewer that works like ordinary folders](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31259/archive-file-format-viewer-that-works-like-ordinary-folders) as that question mention 0% compression rate, which this question is not.

This question is also different from another question - [Application that shows rar-archives as normal files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/application-that-shows-rar-archives-as-normal-files) as that question is still not answer and the question does not describe more in depth.